# How do I capture the results of a YESNOCANCEL MessageBox without gotos/labels in NSIS installer scripting?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, nsis, messagebox

I would like to know how to use a YESNOCANCEL MessageBox in conjunction with IF logic from LogicLib.nsh in NSIS installer scripting to avoid having to use labels and gotos.

Is there any way to capture the result of a MessageBox in a variable of some kind?

Also, I know there are better things than NSIS out there, but using something else isn't a possibility at this point. =(

Note the `{WHAT GOES HERE??}` in the below code.  If this was just an If...Else... it would work fine.

Thanks for the help

```
${If} ${Cmd} `MessageBox MB_YESNOCANCEL|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION 
"PROGRAM X is already installed. Click YES to remove the installed version 
 found in C:\Program Files(x86). Click NO to skip uninstall and choose a 
 different install location (not recommended) or CANCEL to terminate
  the installer." IDYES`

    MessageBox MB_OK "Yes was clicked"
${ElseIf} {WHAT GOES HERE??}
    MessageBox MB_OK "No was clicked"
${Else}    
    MessageBox MB_OK "Cancel was clicked"
${EndIf}
```

**Update**:
I also found this example, but I am not sure what `${||}` does or how it might help me.

```
  ; ifcmd..||..| and if/unless cmd
  StrCpy $R2 ""
  ${IfCmd} MessageBox MB_YESNO "Please click Yes" IDYES ${||} StrCpy $R2 $R2A ${|}
  ${Unless} ${Cmd} `MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_DEFBUTTON2 "Please click No" IDYES`
    StrCpy $R2 $R2B
  ${EndUnless}
  ${If} $R2 == "AB"
    DetailPrint "PASSED IfCmd/If Cmd test"
  ${Else}
    DetailPrint "FAILED IfCmd/If Cmd test"
  ${EndIf}
```

Comment: +1 Good Question. Btw, Do you know how to normally use a label with the MessageBox? You know thats possible right, and it maybe your only option?

Comment: Yup!  That is what I am trying to avoid if at all possible.

Comment: you can just edit/update your question. Delete your comment, click `edit` on your question and add your code in there.

Comment: there are a few NSIS folks here, You might get an answer hopefully in sometime =P

Comment: @giddy

Excellent, I am crossing my fingers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A line ending in `${|}` indicates a if block that executes a single instruction if the condition is true:

```
${IfThen} $Instdir == $Temp ${|} MessageBox mb_ok "$$InstDir equals $$Temp" ${|}
```

This is just shorthand syntax for:

```
${If} $Instdir == $Temp 
    MessageBox mb_ok "$$InstDir equals $$Temp" 
${EndIf}
```

The IfCmd macro uses `${IfThen} ${Cmd}` internally and `${||}` is a hack to end the string quote started by IfCmd, so:

```
${IfCmd} MessageBox MB_YESNO "click yes" IDYES ${||} MessageBox mb_ok choice=IDYES ${|}
```

is shorthand for:

```
${If} ${Cmd} 'MessageBox MB_YESNO "yes" IDYES' ;notice the quotes here
    MessageBox mb_ok choice=IDYES
${EndIf}
```

You can even mix ifthen and labels, but this is ugly IMHO:

```
StrCpy $0 "Cancel"
${IfCmd} MessageBox MB_YESNOCANCEL "Mr. Powers?" IDYES yes IDNO ${||} StrCpy $0 "NO?!" ${|}
MessageBox mb_iconstop $0 ;Cancel or NO
goto end
yes:
MessageBox mb_ok "Yeah baby yeah!"
end:
```

(It is better to just use labels with MessageBox for YESNOCANCEL and ABORTRETRYIGNORE, for YESNO, OKCANCEL etc. that execute different code for both choices, use the ${If} ${Cmd} 'MessageBox ..' .. ${Else} .. ${EndIf} syntax)

Comment: ... and no, you cannot capture the result in a variable, but you could write a !macro wrapper for MessageBox that does this for you...